# C++ Shared_Ptr implementation

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel, template, pointers

I reinvented a c++ smart pointer, `shared_ptr` to be precise. It is meant for practice purpose and does not attempt to replace the standard implementation. To the best of my knowledge, the code works as expected. I decided to skip the custom deleter because I want to keep things simple for now. I would love feedbacks and constructive criticism.

Here is the implementation

### shared.hpp

```
#ifndef SHARED_PTR_H_
#define SHARED_PTR_H_

#include <cstddef>

namespace smp
{
    template<typename T>
    class shared_ptr 
    {
        public:
            explicit shared_ptr(T* ptr = nullptr);
            ~shared_ptr();
            shared_ptr(shared_ptr& ptr);
            shared_ptr operator=(shared_ptr& ptr);
            shared_ptr(shared_ptr&& ptr) noexcept;
            shared_ptr operator=(shared_ptr&& ptr) noexcept;

            T operator*();
            T* operator->() const;

            size_t use_count() const;
            void reset();
            T* get();
            bool unique() const;
            operator bool() const;
            
        private:
            T* obj_ptr;
            struct RefCount {
                size_t use_count_;
                T* object_;
            }* ref_cnt;

    };

    template<typename T>
    shared_ptr<T> make_shared(T object);
}

#endif /* SHARED_PTR_H_ */
```

### shared.cpp

```
#include "shared.hpp"

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

namespace smp
{
    template<typename T>
    shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr(T* ptr)
        : obj_ptr{ptr}, ref_cnt{new RefCount()}
    {
        ref_cnt->object_ = ptr;
        if(ptr)
            ++ref_cnt->use_count_;
    }

    template<typename T>
    shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr(shared_ptr& ptr)
        : ref_cnt{new RefCount()}  
    {
        obj_ptr = ptr.obj_ptr;
        ref_cnt = ptr.ref_cnt;

        ++ref_cnt->use_count_;
    }

    template<typename T>
    shared_ptr<T> shared_ptr<T>::operator=(shared_ptr& ptr)
    {
        obj_ptr = ptr.obj_ptr;
        ref_cnt = ptr.ref_cnt;
        ++ref_cnt->use_count_;

        return *this;
    }

    template<typename T>
    shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr(shared_ptr&& ptr) noexcept
        : obj_ptr{nullptr}, ref_cnt{new RefCount()}
    {
        obj_ptr = std::move(ptr.obj_ptr);
        ref_cnt = std::move(ptr.ref_cnt);

        ptr.reset();
    }

    template<typename T>
    shared_ptr<T> shared_ptr<T>::operator=(shared_ptr&& ptr) noexcept
    {
        if(obj_ptr)
            reset();
        obj_ptr = std::move(ptr.obj_ptr);
        ref_cnt = std::move(ptr.ref_cnt);

        ptr.obj_ptr = nullptr;

        return *this;
    }

    template<typename T>
    shared_ptr<T> make_shared(T object)
    {
        return shared_ptr<T>(new T{object});
    }

    template<typename T>
    T shared_ptr<T>::operator*()
    {
        return *obj_ptr;
    }

    template<typename T>
    T* shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const
    {
        return &*obj_ptr;
    }

    template<typename T>
    size_t shared_ptr<T>::use_count() const
    {
        return ref_cnt->use_count_;
    }

    template<typename T>
    void shared_ptr<T>::reset()
    {
        obj_ptr = nullptr;

        if(ref_cnt)
            --ref_cnt->use_count_;

        if(ref_cnt->use_count_ == 0)
            ref_cnt->object_->~T();
    }

    template<typename T>
    T* shared_ptr<T>::get()
    {
        return obj_ptr;
    }

    template<typename T>
    bool shared_ptr<T>::unique() const
    {
        return (ref_cnt->use_count_ == 1);
    }

    template<typename T>
    shared_ptr<T>::operator bool() const 
    {
        return (obj_ptr != nullptr);
    }
    
    template<typename T>
    shared_ptr<T>::~shared_ptr()
    {
        if(obj_ptr)
            reset();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Overview

Templated classes "normally" should provide all the code at the point of usage. As a result you should probably not have a separate shared.cpp. Though some people put the definitions in a separate shared.tpp file that is included by the header file.

### Code Review:

You are missing a constructor for `nullptr`.

Though `nullptr` can be converted to any other type the compiler can not know what type you want in this situation so you would need to be explicit. But it would be nice to allow auto conversion from `nullptr` to the correct shared pointer type.

```
 void myFunc(smp::shared_ptr<int>&& ptr) { /* Stuff */}

 int main()
 {
     myFunc(nullptr); // This fails.
                      // as you defined an explicit constructor.
                      // But this is totaly safe so it would be nice if it
                      // simply worked rather than forcing the long hand.
 }
```

So I would add a constructor for this situation.

```
 smp::shared_ptr::shared_ptr(std::nullptr_t);
```

---

Non standard copy constructor and move constructor:

```
            shared_ptr(shared_ptr& ptr);           // Would expect const ref
            shared_ptr operator=(shared_ptr& ptr); //
```

In the current state these can not catch temporary values.

---

Most people forget the `noexcept`. So well done.

```
            shared_ptr(shared_ptr&& ptr) noexcept;
            shared_ptr operator=(shared_ptr&& ptr) noexcept;
```

---

You should probably return a reference here:

```
            T operator*();
```

Otherwise you are going to force a copy of the internal object as it is returned. Just like the `operator->` this does not affect the state of the shared pointer so this is const.

In std::shared_ptr this is a noexcept operation. I could personally argue over that. But smarter people than me wrote the standard so I would go with them.

```
            T&       operator*() const noexcept;
```

---

Good.
T* operator->() const;

But like the `operator*` can be `noexcept`.

```
            T* operator->() const noexcept;
```

---

You don't want this accidentally converting in non boolean contexts.

```
            operator bool() const;
```

In this situation:

```
      smp::shared_ptr<int>   x(new int{6});
      smp::shared_ptr<float> y(new float{5});

      if (x == y) {
          // Because of your bool operator
          // they are converted to bool (for both this is true)
          // resulting in this code saying they are equal.
          std::cout << "Equal\n";
      }
```

Use the explicit here:

```
      explicit operator bool() const;
```

---

The issue I have hear is that if the new fails (for RefCount) then you leak the pointer.

Once you had the pointer to the constructor of a shared pointer you are seeding all responsibility of the pointer. That mean if the object fails to correctly construct you need to make sure the passed pointer is deleted. So in the situation of new failing you need to call delete on the pointer.

```
template<typename T>
shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr(T* ptr)
    : obj_ptr{ptr}, ref_cnt{new RefCount()}
{
    ref_cnt->object_ = ptr;
    if(ptr)
        ++ref_cnt->use_count_;
}
```

Add a try catch block to the initializer list:

```
template<typename T>
shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr(T* ptr)
try
    : obj_ptr{ptr}
    , ref_cnt{new RefCount()}
{
    ref_cnt->object_ = ptr;
    if(ptr)
        ++ref_cnt->use_count_;
}
catch(...)
{
    delete ptr;
}
```

---

If you are copying a `shared_ptr` then you should be using the same `ref_cnt` not a brand new one.

You should prefer to do as much work in the initializer list as possible to prevent multiple initializations.

```
    shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr(shared_ptr& ptr)
        : ref_cnt{new RefCount()}  
    {
        obj_ptr = ptr.obj_ptr;
        ref_cnt = ptr.ref_cnt;

        ++ref_cnt->use_count_;
    }
```

// Fixed:

```
    shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr(shared_ptr& ptr)
        : obj_ptr(ptr.obj_ptr)
        , ref_cnt{ptr.ref_cnt}  
    {
        if (obj_ptr) {
            ++ref_cnt->use_count_;
        }
    }
```

---

Here you forget to decrement the ref_counter of the previous object (so potentially allowing a leak). I would use the copy and swap idiom to provide the strong exception guarantee (it also covers self assignment).

```
    template<typename T>
    shared_ptr<T> shared_ptr<T>::operator=(shared_ptr& ptr)
    {
        obj_ptr = ptr.obj_ptr;  // Old object potentially leaked.
        ref_cnt = ptr.ref_cnt;  // Old ref count potentially leaked.
        ++ref_cnt->use_count_;

        return *this;
    }
```

---

Again incorrectly increment the counter.

```
    template<typename T>
    shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr(shared_ptr&& ptr) noexcept
        : obj_ptr{nullptr}, ref_cnt{new RefCount()}
    {
        obj_ptr = std::move(ptr.obj_ptr);
        ref_cnt = std::move(ptr.ref_cnt);

        ptr.reset();
    }
```

The reset will decrement the counter. Since you have moved the object there has been no decrement.

Simpler to simply set this one up as null and then swap.

---

This can fail.

```
    template<typename T>
    shared_ptr<T> shared_ptr<T>::operator=(shared_ptr&& ptr) noexcept
    {
        if(obj_ptr)
            reset();
```

If `ptr` is the only copy. Then calling reset is going to free the object. Thus any other code is going to now manipulate a freeed object.

```
        obj_ptr = std::move(ptr.obj_ptr);
        ref_cnt = std::move(ptr.ref_cnt);


        ptr.obj_ptr = nullptr;
        // If you don't reset the ref count object then
        // eventually `ptr` is going to go out of scope and
        // its destructor is going to mess with the ref count object.
```

Simpler to simply set this one up as null and then swap.

---

Why does the shared object have to be copied constructed?

```
    template<typename T>
    shared_ptr<T> make_shared(T object)
    {
        return shared_ptr<T>(new T{object});
    }
```

Would be nive to allow the type `T` to be constructed using any of its normal constructors that take parameters.

```
    template<typename T, typename... Args>
    shared_ptr<T> make_shared(Args...&& args)
    {
        // Though this is the simplist way to do it.
        // The standard version tries to make the whole thing more efficient.
        // by allocating the space for the object T and the ref-count
        // in a single allocation (thus removing the need for an extra
        // call to new).
        return shared_ptr<T>(new T{std::forward<Args>(args)...});
    }
```

---

```
    template<typename T>
    T* shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const
    {
        return &*obj_ptr; // Not sure why that is rewquired.
    }
```

---

This implies you don't keep a reference count object for nullptr. But your object always has a reference counter and you will need to make sure it is updated correctly.

```
template<typename T>
shared_ptr<T>::~shared_ptr()
{
    if(obj_ptr) // Always call reset.
                // Otherwise you are potentially leaking
                // the reference count object.
        reset();
}
```

---

Which leads us to the reference count object handling. In reset you need to call delete on the object managed and the reference count object if the count reaches zero.

```
template<typename T>
void shared_ptr<T>::reset()
{
    obj_ptr = nullptr;

    if(ref_cnt)
        --ref_cnt->use_count_;

    if(ref_cnt->use_count_ == 0)
        // This is not correct.
        // You have called the destructor but leaked the object space.
        ref_cnt->object_->~T();

        // You need to delete the object and the memory used by the
        // reference count object
        // delete ref_cnt->object_;
        // delete ref_cnt;
}
```

---

Self Plug: Wrote a lot about shared pointers here:

https://lokiastari.com/series/

Read three articles on shared pointers.

Comment: What is the purpose of having a pointer to the object in the control block here? I am not sure I see a usage for it. Is it correct to say that the above implementation of reset is not thread safe? Is introducing a lock the only solution?

Comment: @Jérôme I don't understand your question. I don't see "control block" mentioned in my review above. Thread Safety. Nothing is thread safe unless sombody explicitly says so. Even the standard library does not have thread safe shared pointer. The reason for this is cost. Most situations don't need thread safety, so why should these people pay for the extra cost of something they don't need or want.

Comment: Sorry, by control block I meant "ref_cnt". I am not sure why we need the object_ pointer here. Regarding thread safety, I understand that this has a cost, but somehow the possibility of letting double deletes happens in a thread program (`delete ref_cnt->object_` and `delete ref_cnt`) seems dangerous to me (not sure how the std::shared_ptr handles this).

Comment: OK "ref_cnt". You do need a shared counter, so it can not be local to the object. This is the simplest way of implementing a shared counter (just allocate memory that all the shared pointers use). The `std::shared_ptr` does a slightly better job at it (by allocating in the same block as the object) but at the cost of being more complicated.  I go into a lot more detail in an article I wrote about shared pointers here: [Smart Pointer: Part 2](/https://lokiastari.com/blog/2015/01/15/c-plus-plus-by-example-smart-pointer-part-ii/index.html)

Answer (score 4):

1. I am not sure how it works at all as it shouldn't compile. Generic templates require the whole implementation in .hpp/.h files and nothing hidden in .cpp files aside from some possible instantiations.
2. You have a ton of memory leaking due to `ref_cnt{new RefCount()}` in lots of places.
3. Those are incorrect ways to write copy assignment/operator:

   ```
        shared_ptr(shared_ptr& ptr);
        shared_ptr operator=(shared_ptr& ptr);
   ```

   They should be

   ```
       shared_ptr(const shared_ptr& ptr);
       shared_ptr operator=(const shared_ptr& ptr);
   ```
4. Also, copy-assignment and move-assignment aren't safe for self assignment. E.g., `shared_ptr<T> x = ...; x = x;` results in a bug.
5. `make_shared` is supposed to obtain a bunch of arguments and construct the object with the parameters. As it is, it can only construct copy-constructible objects and it isn't what people want with it. It supposed to go like this

   ```
      template<typename T, typename... Args>
      shared_ptr<T> make_shared(Args&&... args)
      {
           return shared_ptr<T>(new T(std::forwat<Args>(args)...));
      }
   ```

   also, `std::make_shared` saves on the extra allocation of the control block by creating the object and the reference counter together.
6. The reference counter class you use `RefCount` is not thread-safe. The counter is supposed to be atomic. You cannot use this smart pointer in a multi-thread environment safely which is the primary purpose of the `std::shared_ptr`.
7. I believe both `*` and `->` operators are supposed to return `T&` and not `T` or `T*`.
8. `operator bool()` is ought to be `explicit` else you can made odd comparisons.
9. As it is written following line shouldn't compile `shared_ptr<int> x = {};` because it has no default constructor and instead it uses `explicit shared_ptr(T* ptr = nullptr);` which is explicit.
10. You should consider what to do when `T` is a const object. At times people want to pass `shared_ptr<const T>` to some code because they want to make sure that the object isn't modified.
11. You need some more consideration to the object oriented scenario. Frequently people want to create a `Derived` class and return `shared_ptr<Base>` and your class has no support for it. Also you have no support for dynamic casting.

Comment: 6. I doubt `std::shared_ptr` is primarily for concurrency. Though it is certainly used there too. 7. [Look it up.](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator*) He got op* wrong, you got op-> wrong. 9. Shouldn't and does or should but won't? 10. That's a minor aspect of the next point.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` is not thread safe either.

Comment: @MartinYork `shared_ptr` is thread safe. Like, it doesn't do anything about thread safety of the variable it manages - but the control block is.

Comment: @Deduplicator 6. `shared_ptr` is a big overkill if it isn't used in multithreading environment. 9. Go test on your compiler. Don't have time for it and there is no tester supplied. 10/11. Dealing with class hierarchy is quite different from dealing with classifiers in template classes.

Comment: @ALX23z: IS that new in the standard? Can you quote tell me the section in the standard, because I though I read otherwise.

Comment: @MartinYork you wouldn't be able to use `shared_ptr` in multithreaded enviorenment at all if it's control block wasn't thread-safe.

Comment: Well, `shared_ptr` is about shared ownership, which is nearly always overkill (often resulting from muddled thinking). Whether the ownership is shared across threads or not. That was a prompt to clarify your post, me knowing (or not?) is not really relevant. One can deal with the qualifiers without hauling out the big guns, but they will deal with the issue thoroughly too.

Comment: @Deduplicator that's the point that when dealing with multithreading it is never clearly known when object is meant to be destroyed. Thus, shared ownership is needed there.

Comment: @ALX23z so it should be easy to quote the standard then (as it is so important).

Comment: @MartinYork that would be easy if I knew how to navigate standard. Well you can  check cppreference on shared_ptr. In implementation notes they wrote a bit about proper atomic synchronisation.

Comment: The standard does not mention threads (I just re-read to check). So there are no guarantees provided by the standard. Specific implementations may provide extra guarantees over the standard (as long as they document them). Cppreferece talks about control blocks (this is a traditional way of implementing the shared pointer but not the only way (a ring of pointers can also be used)). **BUT** the standard does not mention a specific implementation technique (it never does). The standard talks in terms of pre and post conditions of the object. So nothing is mentioned about a control block.

Comment: @MartinYork can you link reference to standard?

Comment: @ALX23z Find reference to standard here: [Where can I find the C++ standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents/4653479#4653479)  You will find the definition of shared pointer in **20.11.3 Class template shared_ptr  [util.smartptr.shared]**

Comment: @MartinYork checked out one of drafts post C++11 for the `std::shared_ptr`. Honestly, it is poorly written as a technical document. But still it implicitly implies that the control block (or however it is implemented) needs to be thread-safe to satisfy the requirements of `std::shared_ptr`. Even if it not explicitly stated one needs to misunderstand and/or twist meaning and intention of the writer to claim otherwise.

Comment: @ALX23z As I understand it no STD classes are thread safe (as this adds costs). (Though there are some specific notes on streams about it). C++ is all about not paying for what you don't need. So why should a single threaded application pay the cost (it will never need that security) just so a few users don't have to. It is up to the user of the shared pointer to make sure accesses is thread safe. If you found something that says otherwise I would love to read it.

Comment: @MartinYork the very definition implies it: `The shared_ptr class template stores a pointer, usually obtained via new. shared_ptr implements semantics
of shared ownership; the last remaining owner of the pointer is responsible for destroying the object, or otherwise releasing the resources associated with the stored pointer.` It is not explicitly stated but one cannot even reason whether instance is unique or not without ensuring thread safety. The poor documentation part is lack of explicit definitions and vagueness, e.g., what is "shared ownership"?

Comment: @ALX23z Completely disagree. Not even implied that it is thread safe in that statement.

Comment: @MartinYork "last remaining pointer is responsible..." how would it know if it is last remaining pointer if it weren't thread safe?

Comment: @MartinYork let me give a concrete trivial example. Say you have two threads each having an instance of a shared pointer. Those are the only instances of the shared pointer. When both threads go out of scope - in your opinion - does the definition implies that the pointer's destruction must be called exactly once?

Comment: @MartinYork *the shared pointer instances manage the same pointer.

Comment: @ALX23z If shared_ptr was thread safe then it would talk about what would happen under **"data race"** conditions. It does not so there is no implication (explicit or implied) of it working in a multi threaded environment (just like all other std types (none are thread safe (except those specifically designed mutex/condition_variable/atomic etc...)). `std::shared_ptr` has undefined behavior if a "Data Race" happens it is your responsibility to make sure that such a data race does not happen by using the appropriate thread controls (mutex/atomic/condition_variables etc).

Comment: **does the definition implies that the pointer's destruction must be called exactly once?** Nope. This is undefined behavior as you have let a "Data Race" happen. See: Section 6.9.2 Multi-threaded executions and data races [intro.multithread] paragraph 21 => **The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two potentially concurrent conflicting actions, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other, except for the special case for signal handlers described below. Any such data race results in undefined behavior.**

Comment: @MartinYork but it clearly and explicitly states so - definition promises that the destructor is called once. Yet you claim the opposite. It doesn't help your case to state an unrelated part of the standard.

Comment: **it gives promise that the destructor is called once** This only holds true if there is no undefined behavior. Rather than us discussing it in comments I have opend a question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65584420/stdshared-ptr-thread-safe

Comment: @MartinYork but where is undefined behavior? You have two distinct instances of an object that go out of scope from two different threads. How is this undefined behaviour?

Comment: @ALX23z Its undefined behavior because you have a "Data Race"

Comment: @MartinYork but there is no data race because definition of `std::shared_ptr` implies that the destructor is called once. There is nothing about multiple threads invalidating it in any manner. Also the `stdshared-ptr-thread-safe` is a duplicate.

Comment: @ALX23z Make your argument on the linked question. Lets see how many votes you get. The standard never implies things. They are either explicitly defined, undefined behavior or implementation specific.

Comment: @MartinYork I believe you misunderstand where data races can potentially happen in the standard. They occur when two multiple threads operate on the same object - same memory. This is just the general rule. Of course if explicitly stated function/method can be thread safe. E.g., if same `shared_ptr`'s reference was forwarded to two threads then operating on it causes a data race. However, in the example two threads have different instances of `shared_ptr`. It is just that the instances happen to manage the same object. It is implementation responsibility to ensure safe destruction call.

Comment: @MartinYork and it is explicitly stated in the standard that the destruction call must be done once by the `shared_ptr`. Nothing says that multithreading invalidates it.

Comment: There are a lot of comments here, please make sure that if you have any information that should be added to the Answer that you do edit it in.  Also please remember that Comments can be deleted at any time, so that anything left in them could be lost at any time.

Answer (score 1):

I will add my 2 cents to the list.

```cpp
    T* obj_ptr;
    struct RefCount {
        size_t use_count_;
        T* object_;
    }* ref_cnt;
```

Here, you are duplicating `T*` pointer.
It would be better to remove `RefCount` struct and just keep `T*` and a `size_t*` member. The benefit would be lower memory usage in the heap.

```cpp
    T* obj_ptr;
    size_t* use_count;
```

Some might suggest you to remove the `obj_ptr` member (which is also a good way) but the 2-pointers solution will greatly ease my next point.

This constructor and copy operator don't allow copies from `shared_ptr` of child class of `T`.

```cpp
    shared_ptr(shared_ptr& ptr);
    shared_ptr operator=(shared_ptr& ptr);
```

You may want to allow it with:

```cpp
    template<class U>
    shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<U>& ptr);
    template<class U>
    shared_ptr operator=(const shared_ptr<U>& ptr);
```